# How can I keep an environment all on one page?

Tags: page-breaking, environments, boxes

In other words, how can I forbid pagination between `\myenv` and `\endmyenv`?  I thought at first to make the whole thing a box; if I'm not mistaken---this would prevent TeX from breaking it up---but I don't know how to do that in an environment...environment.

I have a not-MWE, but I feel like this question is sufficiently general that it doesn't need one; it may even be a duplicate that I failed to find.

Comment: wrap it in a `minipage`, e.g `\newenvironment{myenvironmnet}{\begin{minipage}{<width>}}{\endminipage}`

Comment: I agree, it's a duplicate.